# Displaymath with name?

Tags: displaystyle

In the displaymath environment the mathematical equation is usually placed in a separate line in the document. Is there a way to give the equation a left aligned name, as A1, on the same line, while the equation stays centered?

Comment: Probably several, such as an `equation` with the `[leqno]` option. If you want a name separate from the equation number, you might have an aligned first column in which you insert `\text`.